# FXBlurView Background Lagging

Tags: ios, uiview, blur

I'm using [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) for my background blurs on my UIViews. I'm using the default settings, which means that it updates every frame. However, for some reason, the background seems to lag a bit. Here is a GIF of the issue I'm having:
[BlurGIF http://www.interdazzle.com/misc/forums/BlurGIF.gif](http://www.interdazzle.com/misc/forums/BlurGIF.gif)
If anyone could help, that would be wonderful.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I changed my code a bit to match what Nick suggested, and came up with this:
When it is initialized:

```
   self.sidebar.blurRadius = 30;
    self.sidebar.dynamic = NO;
    self.sidebar.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
    [self.sidebar updateAsynchronously:YES completion:^{
        self.sidebar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

    }];
```

When I animate it:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    BOOL open = self.sidebar.frame.size.width >= 250;
    self.sidebar.frame = CGRectMake(open? -250: 0, self.sidebar.frame.origin.y, open? 0: 250, self.sidebar.frame.size.height);
}];
```

However, it doesn't seem to update/position correctly. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @NickLockwood's question:
When the FXBlurView is initiated, I run this code:

```
self.sidebar.blurRadius = 30;
self.sidebar.dynamic = NO;
self.sidebar.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight;
self.sidebar.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityBottomLeft;
[self.sidebar setClipsToBounds:YES];
[self.sidebar updateAsynchronously:YES completion:^{
    // Whatever you want
}];
```

Then I simply animate the object like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        BOOL open = self.sidebar.frame.size.width > 125; // Over half way done
        self.sidebar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, open? 0 : 250, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    }];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FXBlurView can't always keep up if the size of the view is very large, or the underlying view is very complex.

There is a trick for doing this efficiently, where you only render the blur once and then adjust the visible area instead of redrawing it every frame. If you look at the sliding overlay example included with FXBlurView, you can see how this is done.

Comment: That isn't quite right. You'll need to animate the width, not the left edge, otherwise the background won't be positioned correctly since it is pinned to the left of the view and you don't want it to move.

Comment: Put your controls in a subview of fixed size inside the sidebar blur view, pinned to the right. Then when you animate the sidebar width from zero to 250, the controls will appear to slide in and the background image will appear correctly.